# Why conversion works on the idle but not executing the program?

Tags: scapy, converters

I'm playing with scapy library in python3 (https://github.com/phaethon/scapy) and sniffing the packets on the net, I get these format of packets, here are some examples:

```
b'\xe8t\xe6,\xf1:0\x10\xb3\x18\x8b\xfd\x08\x00E\x00\x00b\xe7\xb1@\x00@\x06\xf2j\xc0\xa8\x01h\xd8:\xc6.\xd2B\x01\xbb\xa1\x9a\xbf\x1e\x0b"q\xc1\x80\x18\x00\xfe^\x95\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n\x00CX6)\x818P\x17\x03\x03\x00)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x8d\xdc\x86`:\xe9\x8f=\xec\x89u~\xdf\x7f\x1aN\x85\xf4ESt\xa0oT\xdba\xfan\xc7\xb8\x01\xf8\t'
```

or

```
b'\xe8t\xe6,\xf1:0\x10\xb3\x18\x8b\xfd\x08\x00E\x00\x01\x03\xe3\x9e@\x00@\x06\xda\xbe\xc0\xa8\x01h\xc0|\xf9\n\xcc6\x01\xbbDo\x9a\xe4N\xaf\x11~\x80\x18\x05\xa4\xc6x\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n\x00CY\xed`\xa8Vb\x17\x03\x03\x00\xca\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004;wn,\x13\x8d9\x17G\xee/\x1c\x15\x12,\xc0\xde\xf4\xab\xa5emvZ\xf5\x1f\x94\x8a\xcc4g>@\xb9\xf2dYs\xeb<l;\x8b\x8a\xccT\n\xacUT\x049\xcbp\x1c#\x87z\\[8\xde\xd7I\x14\xfd\x94\x81\x13x`\x9eH\xd8\xbc)lc\x0fE\xfc\x99F\xb0c\xb9v\x86\x1c\xc4\xec\x14\xb6\x00\x1e\x8f\xd5\x08H/\xa4\xea\xf4~2\x90\xc7\xabJ\xb9\x9f\xf9\x06\xc6\xe5$\xe4(\xab#\xd8\xf4<\x7f\xfa\xe6Y_\x80\x14\xb2H\x10\x1cT\xdf\x1f\x0f\xbb\xce\xf8\xbe q\xf3=qQ\xd2a!e\x8a\xbf9Y\x7f\xb8\xe5Bo\xd8\r\xcb\xcf\x01H\xf8x\x90\x98\xfc>$\xef>\x80;\xa9\xf9\x7f\x9f\xc5?V\xecH:\x7f\xfeb\xa5E\xab'
```

The weird thing, is that if I try to convert them to idle3, typing:

```
> from scapy.all import *
> text = b'blablablabytesstring'
> text2 = Ether(text)
> text2
```

And it works, it correctly converts.

But if I do the same thing, but writing a simple script, like:

```
from scapy.all import *

text = b'sameblablablabytesstringasidle3'

text2 = Ether(text)

print (text2)
```

It doesn't converts, and it prints the same bytes string.

Why? How can I solve this?

**--UPDATE--**

This is the output of text2.show()

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = e8:74:e6:2c:f1:3a
  src       = 30:10:b3:18:8b:fd
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4
     ihl       = 5
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 259
     id        = 24485
     flags     = DF
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = tcp
     chksum    = 0x5eb8
     src       = 192.168.1.104
     dst       = 192.124.249.10
     \options   \
###[ TCP ]###
        sport     = 51172
        dport     = https
        seq       = 3204149667
        ack       = 3154139287
        dataofs   = 8
        reserved  = 0
        flags     = PA
        window    = 1444
        chksum    = 0xb3ea
        urgptr    = 0
        options   = [('NOP', None), ('NOP', None), ('Timestamp', (4182786, 1620720294))]
###[ Raw ]###
           load      = b'\x17\x03\x03\x00\xca\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xba\xc1\xa0H\xa2\xb3\t\x02:P>\x8b\xeb\xaa\xbd\x83H\x05\x1f(\x02\x80\x9e\x96\xa5\xd9\xf7\xf4\x07&s\xfd6\xb9 \x00\x8c\xcf\xd7\xe4\x04pQ\x992"$\x07R\x02\xb4\x97\xad!\xafB\xc8I\xa6\xe6\x18\xc7x\x16\x9a$c\xc4\x05}\xffl\xe7\x89\x93\xa4\x9a\xf1\x90\x8d\xde"\xe0\xb2\x06\x14(Yk\xf441\xbf\xfa?\xd4puE\x97\xcd\xb1\xc2\xfaaa\x14{\xd4f\x80\xb9\x81keO\x90\x13\x9c\x01\xaa\xe4}\xab{\xd8\x9a\xb3\xe3\x88\xcd:5\xe1\xa9\xd6:\x06l_\xed\xb3\x96=\xcc\x0f?c\xf7\xad\xed\xde\xca||\xd6\xbc\xa4\x99u\xff\xbcI\xe2\x8cQ\xe3\x87\x9f\x18(\rp\x04u\xad\r\xa55\xbe`q\x1b=`5\'\xbc\xf2\x0b\xb9V\x1ecp'
```

**--UPDATE2--
(from idle3)**

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?). This affects only IPv6
>>> text = b"0\x10\xb3\x18\x8b\xfd\xe8t\xe6,\xf1:\x08\x00E\xa0\x004a'@\x004\x06\x90\xa2\x173{\x1b\xc0\xa8\x01d\x00P\xec\xe6\x01\x81%|\xfcY@8\x80\x10\x03\xd4(\xbe\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\nx\x93UR\x00\x00\xd7$"
>>> text2 = Ether(text)
>>> text2
<Ether  dst=e8:74:e6:2c:f1:3a src=30:10:b3:18:8b:fd type=0x800 |<IP  version=4 ihl=5 tos=0x0 len=98 id=59313 flags=DF frag=0 ttl=64 proto=tcp chksum=0xf26a src=192.168.1.104 dst=216.58.198.46 options=[] |<TCP  sport=53826 dport=https seq=2711273246 ack=186806721 dataofs=8 reserved=0 flags=PA window=254 chksum=0x5e95 urgptr=0 options=[('NOP', None), ('NOP', None), ('Timestamp', (4413494, 696334416))] |<Raw  load=b'\x17\x03\x03\x00)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x8d\xdc\x86`:\xe9\x8f=\xec\x89u~\xdf\x7f\x1aN\x85\xf4ESt\xa0oT\xdba\xfan\xc7\xb8\x01\xf8\t' |>>>>
```

**--UPDATE3-- (print from program.py)**

```
Ether / IP / TCP 192.168.1.104:53826 > 216.58.198.46:https PA / Raw
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `text2.show()` instead of `print(text2)` and see how that goes?

```
from scapy.all import *

text = b'\xe8t\xe6,\xf1:0\x10\xb3\x18\x8b\xfd\x08\x00E\x00\x00b\xe7\xb1@\x00@\x06\xf2j\xc0\xa8\x01h\xd8:\xc6.\xd2B\x01\xbb\xa1\x9a\xbf\x1e\x0b"q\xc1\x80\x18\x00\xfe^\x95\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n\x00CX6)\x818P\x17\x03\x03\x00)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x8d\xdc\x86`:\xe9\x8f=\xec\x89u~\xdf\x7f\x1aN\x85\xf4ESt\xa0oT\xdba\xfan\xc7\xb8\x01\xf8\t'
text2 = Ether(text)
text2.show()
```

Comment: if I replace print with show(), now the output it's different.. but it's still not the same of the print(text2) in the idle3. I pasted the output in the main.

Comment: @alexj can you paste an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: @alexj how about print(text2.summary())

Comment: updated again the main post. It's a "summary" as well. Anyway we are always closer. Thanks for help until now @noob123 !

Comment: @alexj I can't seem to get it printed in the format you would like.  What are you using the info for?

Comment: it's for a sniffer script.

Comment: Sorry. I can't really figure out how to have it print exactly like the interpreter without setting it up yourself.